# Strings arguments outputted by PHP echo method Can't be pass on to javascript functions

Tags: javascript, php, html, function, arguments

I'm having a situation where I have to pass the php variables as arguments in a function to be used in javaScript later on but the string arguments are not working only integers are working.

```php
<?php 

$product = apples;

$quantity = 5;

echo '<button onclick = "carryOut('.$quantity.','.$product.')">Click me</button>';

?>

<script>
function carryOut(q,p){
alert(q);
alert(p);
}
</script>
```

when I write it as

`onclick = "carryOut('.$quantity.',\'apples\')"`

its working but thats not what I'm trying to do.

Comment: You have practically identified the issue yourself - when you hardcoded the value, you quoted it. But you didn't quote the variable.

Comment: I tried that too

Answer (score 0):

Your original code will (assuming that `$product = apples;` should be `$product = "apples";` to avoid a PHP syntax error) output this:

```
<button onclick = "carryOut(5,apples)">Click me</button>
```

This will cause a JS error because `apples` is meant to be a string literal, and therefore needs to be inside quote marks.

So you just need to add some (escaped) quote marks around the value you expect will be a string:

```
$product = "apples";
$quantity = 5;
echo '<button onclick = "carryOut('.$quantity.',\''.$product.'\')">Click me</button>';
```

Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d3465133e571186d423e5433b71033ea1905a306

This will output

```
<button onclick = "carryOut(5,'apples')">Click me</button>
```

with the hard-coded "apples" string correctly quoted in the resulting JavaScript.

This then works nicely when used in the web page. Demo:

```js
function carryOut(q, p) {
  alert(q);
  alert(p);
}
```

```html
<button onclick = "carryOut(5,'apples')">Click me</button>
```

Comment: the output is still surrounded by single qoutes

Comment: @MatheusMbongeMK And that's a problem because...?? I've done what you asked for. The way you wrote it before, it wasn't working because literal strings in JS need quote marks round them. I've put quote marks round them. Now you're complaining about the quote marks. Have you tested it? Does it work?

Comment: I've added extra info to the answer to prove that what I've done is what you're asking for, and works correctly. If you're still having a problem, you'll need to clarify the exact issue, and also make sure you've applied my changes correctly to your own code.

Comment: you right ,checking the source codes the &gt tag of the opening button tag is highlighted with the error : index.php:342 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: and this is caused by the same code codes you told because as soon as remove them everything is back to normal

Comment: By "everything is back to normal" you mean as it was at the start of your question, still not working? I don't know what other state it could have returned to. But anyway I have proved above that my code works, and does it is supposed to do, based on the information you gave in your question. If you're having that error in your code when you try to use it, I can only assume that the way you're using it together with other code is causing this problem. By itself, there is no problem with this code. You can see it in the demos I provided.

Comment: If you need help with that extra problem you'll need to edit your question to include a) this new error message and b) a code example which actually produces that error (because as I've shown, the code I've written doesn't produce it by itself). If not, please accept my answer because it correctly answers the question that you asked based on the information you provided.

Comment: @MatheusMbongeMK Re your question edit: now you've edited it to include my code (although you still have `$product = apples;` which cannot be your real PHP code, it would make a syntax error). So it should work. Yet you haven't changed your description or included anything else which would demonstrate why you still have an error, or what the error is. So now your question just doesn't make sense any more. I'm tempted to roll it back unless you can make a further update which makes more sense and provides more details of your current problem.

Comment: Small side point: `$product = apples;` would merely raise a warning `Use of undefined constant apples - assumed 'apples'`, not a syntax error (well, at least for PHP versions < 8), so it's possible that OP's code runs.

Comment: @El_Vanja good point. But actually if it does run, the result would be the same in <8 as if the string is quoted: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/07c225540ae98628ab0972df2f0d77d87bda872c

Comment: Agreed. Just wanted to verify that it's likely it's actual code, and also that it's very likely the error is elsewhere.